# I have crashed all of my Java JRE's and any ability to run any programs, after installing netbeans 7.1.2

Tags: java, netbeans-7

I installed Netbeans 7.1.2 to my computer yesterday and it crashed all java functionality. I chose to upgrade because the 7.1 beta IDE that I had installed on this PC, did not recognize the diamonds in the treeset function.

I had several versions installed, including jre 5, 12 that was necessary for an older program to function. I cannot not install any versions now. I get a prompt indicating I need jre 1.6.0_23.msi. I don't have an .msi file to install from, it is just the java executable. I cannot locate this msi file to trick the install. I also cannot find a registry entry that points to the location that the install program is pointing towards. It is a network drive that does not have the indicated folder on it. (\E10001081).

Does anybody here have any suggestions for cleaning up corrupted java installations? If I try to remove the SDK's or JRE's in add/remove programs (XP PRO), I get a fatal error on one and on the remainder the program cannot be found.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful when you close someone's post, to tell them where else they may post correctly. I am learning to program in java as part of my degree program. I am new to this site and need help. I have posted questions pertaining to programs I am writing. Now I cannot continue having blown up my java capability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all previous versions of Java at Oracle's site
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/archive-139210.html

I would start by uninstalling all versions that can be uninstalled, and then installing again all the versions that I need, from the oldest to the newest.

Comment: I have already tried unstalling the previous versions, as well as reinstalling. None will process to completion.

Comment: I did a quick search for "Java uninstaller" and it seems that you are not the only one having this problem. Here are some links that propose solutions: http://singularlabs.com/software/javara/, http://forums.techguy.org/all-other-software/977873-corrupt-java-cant-uninstall-old.html,

Comment: Both of these solutions look just like the errors that I am experiencing. I will try these and see if I am able to recover. Thanks for looking.

Comment: Just wanted to send you a thanks for your suggestions.The second one was a success. I was able to reinstall 6.32 jre and programs are functioning well now. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: You 're welcome; it would be kind of you to accept my answer and/or mark my comment as useful -- unless you can't since this question is closed...